# Titanium WebView - Is there a way to stop it opening a system app?

Tags: ios, google-maps, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm working on a very simple app at the moment that has a tabgroup which open's up various webviews containing different URLs.

One of the webviews is a google maps link, on the device I am using it has the Google Maps App installed. Instead of opening the link in the google maps website, it opens up the link in the App instead. If I test the app in a simulator without the google maps app installed, the webview will load the website version instead.

Is there a way to stop the device from using the system app and force it to use the website instead? So far I have been unable to find any information.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought. May be you can make use of webview's **beforeload** event and examine the url being loaded. And force it to open in your webview?

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of surprised that the WebView is doing what you're describing.  I would expect it to directly load the contents of the URL you've provided, regardless of whether another app is registered for that URL scheme.  But I'll take your word for it.

I have two ideas on this:

- could you use ti.map instead of a google maps URL?  I'm not sure what your map contains; this may not be practical for you
- could you use HTTPClient to retrieve the HTML from the google maps URL, and then call WebView.setHtml() with that HTML?  I would imagine you might have to add a  element to the HTML to get all the relative URLs in the page to work...